# Excel VBA: failing to Activate a worksheet from within sub Workbook_Activate() when workbook is not trusted on opening

Tags: excel, vba

I am experiencing a tricky problem that I could really use some help with.

I have a macro workbook on our servers that our clients download and get reports from. When the workbook is downloaded from our server and the macros begin running after opening (after the user clicks 'enable content'/'enable macros' warnings), the workbook throws an error. We have code that runs in Workbook_Activate() which takes a few actions and then tries Sheets("XYZ").Activate. It is this that fails with a run time 1004 error.

What is strange is that seems to be happening only on specific versions of Excel (for example, Office 365, version 1902 (Build 11328.20564)). Also, if the user saves the Excel file to another location on his machine that is trusted (i.e. no Excel warning prompts on workbook open), the workbook opens and the code runs successfully.

I did find this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2745652/object-model-calls-may-fail-from-workbookopen-event-when-exiting-prote and have since moved the initialization code to Workbook_Open() as the article recommends, just on the off chance that this was the issue. However, the xlsm continues to exhibit the issue when downloaded from our server, only this time the error occurs in Workbook_Open().

Any ideas on what the issue is and/or what I can try next?

This issue is made more tricky by the fact that I don't have a version of Office that shows the problem.  Does MS provide older version of Office for testing purposes? (I can post this as a separate question if that is better).

Thanks,
Simon.

Comment: If you trust the document, close it and open it again does it work? If you trust the network location before opening, does it work? What do you mean by "Downloaded from our server"? Is this file being shared from one company to another or is the server internal?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, once trusted the document opens & runs successfully. I have not tried trusting the web address first in Excel - I will ask if the user has rights to do this and try it out. Download from the server = log into our portal via a web browser, browse to the reports page and click a link to download the xlsm.  Thanks v much.

Comment: ok, so there is no such option to trust a web address / location. I can get them to download the xlsm file to a specific folder that they have marked as trusted. I suspect that this will work, but will ask them to try to confirm. thanks.